# How to remove ANTLR3 Warning 'multiple alternatives'

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, context-free-grammar

I found number of questions related to 'multiple alternatives'in stackoverflow but nothing was much helpful. Here is a part of my g file in antlr3.

```
statement:
    selection_stmt
    | expression_stmt 
    | compound_stmt
    | iteration_stmt
    | return_stmt
    ;

selection_stmt:
    IF OPENB expression CLOSB statement (ELSE statement)?
    ;

expression:
    (var ASSIGN expression) => assignment 
    | simple_expression
    ;
```

The problem I'm facing is I get following warning for the phrase `ELSE statement` above.

> (200): Decision can match input such as "ELSE" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were 
>    disabled for that input

Can someone explain me what happens here? Thank you.

P.S.
When I use a syntactic predicate as `((ELSE)=>ELSE statement)?`, warning disappears. I don't get the reason for this too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***Bhathiya wrote:***
>
> *Can someone explain me what happens here? Thank you.*

Lets's say your input is:

```
if (A) if (B) return 1 else return 2
```

Your grammar is ambiguous: the parser does not "know" how to interpret this. It could do so in two ways (I added braces to emphasize to which `if` the `else` block belongs to):

## 1

```
if (A) 
{
  if (B)
  {
    return 1
  }
  else
  {
    return 2
  }
}
```

[image]

## 2

```
if (A)
{
  if (B)
  {
    return 1
  }
}
else
{
  return 2
}
```

[image]

> ***Bhathiya wrote:***
>
> *P.S. When I use a syntactic predicate as `((ELSE)=>ELSE statement)?`, warning disappears. I don't get the reason for this too.*

By adding a predicate before `ELSE`, you're forcing the parser to choose for option #1 (and the parser does not warn anymore because you're explicitly telling it to choose alternative #1 over #2). Which results in the same as *not* putting a predicate there, but then ANTLR will warn you about it and mentions it will disregard option #2 and will also choose #1 (the message: *"As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input"*).

Now, the answer to your question in the title, *"how to remove warning 'multiple alternatives'?"*, would be to make your grammar unambiguous (or just leave the predicate there, but realize there will never be a *parse* as shown in option #2!). You can do this by introducing some sort of statement-block-delimiters, like `{` and `}`. Or do as Python does it: make the amount of indented white spaces make a distinction to which `if` an `else` belongs to. The choice is yours.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is great. What I want is the 1st option.

Comment: Cool, then all you need is the predicate. And you're welcome @Bhathiya.

Comment: I have few more questions here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656744/issues-of-error-handling-with-antlr3) Can you please have a look? Thanks.